# Django How can I delete an article that belongs to a certain user only?

Tags: python, django

I am trying to create a delete button in my blog, but I don't know how to let the user delete only his own articles.

I was thinking to something like this:

**views.py**

```
@login_required(login_url='/user')
def article_effacer(request, slug):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        user = request.user
        article = get_object_or_404(Article, slug=slug)

        if [check if article belongs to the user]:
            article.delete()
        else:
            pass
    else:
        return HttpResponseForbidden()
```

**template.html**

```
<a class="delete" href='{% url "article.views.article_effacer" a.slug %}'>Effacer</a>
```

**models.py**

```
class Article(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, default='1')
    titre = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    summary = models.TextField(max_length=266)
    contenu = models.TextField(max_length=2000)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=40)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="likes")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.titre

    [... unrelated code ...]
```

I also don't want to show the **template.html** delete button to other users if the article doesn't belong to them, how can I do it ?

Comment: Can you please add your `models.py`?

Comment: @RodXavier Yes just did it.

Comment: `article = get_object_or_404(Article, slug=slug)` returns an object, not a queryset. SO `article.filter` will not work.

Comment: @karthikr Yes that's where I am struggling, I don't understand how to connect the user and the article.

Comment: @Sia in addition to that, `if article.objects.filter(id=user.id, pk=id).exists():` id has no value at this point, so cannot be used as a right-hand value.

Comment: @JonKiparsky I made an update, It's easier to understand now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try something like this:

```
@login_required(login_url='/user')
def article_effacer(request, slug):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        user = request.user
        Article.objects.filter(slug=slug, user=user).delete()
    else:
        return HttpResponseForbidden()
```

However, there is an obvious danger here: I don't recall whether SlugField is unique in django, but I don't believe it is based on a quick glance at the docs. This means that a user who recycles a slug would delete all articles with that slug when they hit this view. Probably not what you want. 
If I were implementing something like this, I would research this and ensure that slugs were unique in my model.

Comment: Slugs are unique, if I delete an article everything should be deleted the slug with it. also `Article.filter(slug=slug, user=user).delete()` return `type object 'Article' has no attribute 'filter'`

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Edited

Comment: Thanks for this answer, it works great, now how can I not show in the template the delete button to unknown users ?

Comment: This sounds like another question, which would require seeing some other code. But speaking in general terms, you're going to check whether the current user==article.user, and only display the button if that is true. There are a number of ways to go about this, though, so I don't want to go into it in the comments to this question.

Answer (score 1):

views.py

```
 @login_required(login_url='/user')
 def article_effacer(request, slug):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        user = request.user
        article = get_object_or_404(Article, slug=slug)

        if article.user == user:
            article.delete()
    else:
        return HttpResponseForbidden()
```

templates.html

```
{% if a.user == user %}<a class="delete" href='{% url "article.views.article_effacer" a.slug %}'>Effacer</a>{% endif %}
```